# Looking to send user input to a web server with swift and load the results

Tags: ios, swift, post

I've never used swift before and am attempting to write an app. I want the user to be able to enter a certain number and then the app end that number to a webpage I host that's written in php which validates the number and sends back of a response of either: Valid or invalid. I was wondering what's the best/easiest way to go about this?

No need for anyone to write any code for me just any advice where to start would be appreciated.

Im writing this app in Xcode 10 using swift 5 currently. I've done some reading and come across a couple of different things that sound like they may be what I need. This includes, POST, GET, URLsessions and Alamofire. If anyone with more experience can lend some insight if I'm on the right path.

Comment: Your on the right track... use URLSession.dataTask to send a POST request with the number. Remember to set the Content-Type and Accept headers for the type of response you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your endpoint URL to `URLRequest`, set its `httpMethod`, headers and include the number as a body parameter using `httpBody`. Then use the shared `URLSession` to create a `URLSessionDataTask` with that request and call `resume()` to kick it off.

Something like

```
let endpointURL = URL(string: "yourEndpointURL")!
var request = URLRequest(url: endpointURL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Accept", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json; charset=utf-8")
let bodyParameters = ["number": 0]
request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyParameters, options: [])
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
dataTask.resume()
```

[URLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest)

[URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession)

[URLSessionDataTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatatask)

Comment: ok cool thanks a lot, ill give this some tests and see how it goes.